# Planet of the Aves Series

Tags: discussion, reference

As you all know there is a series of questions that have been asked about the world existing with birds replacing mammals as the dominant order.

Below should a summarized list of all of the questions in order of post, so that a link to this meta post should be enough for future questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order of oldest to newest;

1. [Planet of the Aves: First Steps](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51374/planet-of-the-aves-first-steps)
2. [Planet of the Aves: Quadrabirds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51622/planet-of-the-aves-quadrabirds)
3. [Planet of the Aves: Aquabirds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51661/planet-of-the-aves-aquabirds)
4. [Planet of the Aves: Low tech Weaponry](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53098/planet-of-the-aves-low-tech-weaponry)
5. [Planet of the Aves: Medieval Armor](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54271/planet-of-the-aves-medieval-armor)
6. [Planet of the Aves: Knowledge of Aerodynamics and Weather Phenomena](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54532/planet-of-the-aves-knowledge-of-aerodynamics-and-weather-phenomena)
7. [Planet of the Aves: New Nests](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55302/planet-of-the-aves-new-nests)
8. [Planet of the Aves: Tool Use](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55370/planet-of-the-aves-tool-use)